# difference between arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

[image]

So, I have grayscale image as 3 RGB channels.
I take the difference between two channels and see, that a take different results, when I take difference between `images[0]` and `images[1]` and when I take difference between `images[1]` and `images[0]`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please post code and output as _formatted text_ not images.

Comment: Also, does the fact that `3 - 1 == 2`, but `1 - 3 == -2` surprise you? It's no different with arrays.

Comment: but currently i have different numbers,not signs

Comment: Are you sure your numbers are actually _signed_ in the first place?

Comment: no,how can i cast arrays to signed?

Answer (score 1):

Observe:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a, b = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> a - b
array([ 62,  10, 126, 206, 157,  36, 170,  42,  54,   1], dtype=uint8)
>>> b - a
array([194, 246, 130,  50,  99, 220,  86, 214, 202, 255], dtype=uint8)

>>> a.astype(np.int) - b.astype(np.int)
array([  62, -246, -130,  -50,  -99,   36,  -86,   42,   54,    1])
>>> b.astype(np.int) - a.astype(np.int)
array([-62, 246, 130,  50,  99, -36,  86, -42, -54,  -1])
```

RGB images contain *unsigned* (nonnegative only) 8-bit integers, so all operations will return `np.uint8`:

```
>>> np.uint8(1) - np.uint8(5)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
252  # not -4
>>> np.int8(1) - np.int8(5)
-4
```

Comment: a) you didn't say a single thing about norms in your post; b) this still boils down to the exact same issue. You should decide what data type you want to use.